# Reuse Cipher but change IV

Tags: java, encryption, initialization-vector

For performance reasons, we would like to reuse our Cipher object (java) for a given key whenever possible. However, we would like to follow good crypto hygiene and use a random IV on every set of plaintext to encrypt. Is it possible to reuse the same cipher object, change the IV, AND do that all without reinitializing the cipher object each time (i.e., only initialize once in the beginning)? I want it to use a new IV after every doFinal call. I can set it manually after every doFinal call if necessary.

I thought about extending IVParameterSpec and overriding the getIV method so that it generates a random one every time, but, I have two problems with that:

1. Probably wouldn't be an issue in practice but how do I know that a given CipherSpi object doesn't call this twice for a given plaintext? I would need to return the same IV for a given plaintext but a different IV for different plaintext. I imagine most providers wouldn't call this twice but I don't know that for sure.
2. Looking at the CipherSpi docs, it looks like it gets passed the IVParameterSpec on initialize and I have no idea if the provider will then get the IV immediately and then cache it for the life of the object. If it does that then the IV would always be the same, regardless of whether the plaintext to encrypt is different.

Is there a different way to reuse the Cipher object but change the IV after every doFinal call that doesn't require reinitializing it? I am aware that some modes like SIV have less stringent IV requirements but that is not an option right now. Also, I am aware that I can pick a particular provider that might support the solution I described above but I was hoping for a solution that is provider-agnostic.

Thanks!

Comment: How often do you have to change the key? If it is less than 1.000.000 times per hour you can stop because your optimization will not have any significant effect (assumption).

Comment: How often do I have to change the key or the IV? There are thousands of different keys being used and that is planned to scale up to millions. The IV needs to be different for each plaintext (i.e., after each doFinal call).

Comment: So you want to process millions of ciphertexts **per second**?

Comment: No, not millions per second. However, the server(s) hosting the application are used for other things as well, some fairly resource intensive, so we would like to do things efficiently. I hear you on over optimization but if there is a clean solution that works then I want to implement it.

Comment: Then may be you should focus on optimizing these resource intensive procedures. There you have a chance to implement an optimization that will have an measurable effect.

Answer (score 0):

Per my understanding, you can use fixed initialization vector and prepend random bytes prefix to each message. There's overhead of additional AES invocation per message, however it's nothing compare to the time needed to initialize `Cipher`. In my case, the approach with random prefix was about 100 times faster (encrypt and decrypt 6-128 length messages in 16 threads with `Cipher` in `ThreadLocal`).